# Database path not been used by application - Logic issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fmdb

I have created a `sqlite` database. and dragged it on to my projects resource folder.

In my project i am accessing a sqlite file from

```
/Users/user12/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/1F219005-A4ED-4794-81FC-65EEF8D243EF/Documents/db.sqlite
```

I am not using the sqlite file that was added to the project. and my project is accessing the DB file from the above location.

So, now when i try to launch my application from a different mac i am unable to launch the application because the DB is not found in that path. So how could i solve this ?

note: i used `FMDB`.

My final objective is to give this application to my client and since he will be running the app on his iPhone, he should be able to access the sqlite file with no issue. So what changes should i make ?

Answer (score 0):

Surely xcode in other machine will have a different path. Try to place the sqlite file at the app path created by xcode on the new machine.

EDIT:
To do what you've said in your comment i suggest to [create an ad-hoc certificate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html). Then use [xcode to create your archive](http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/).
But the path of your `sqlite` file should be in your main bundle.
ps: You need the `UDID`s of your client iPhones to add the devices to the portal.

Comment: I need to give the app to my client, and he should be able to run it on his phone. So where should i have my sqlite file so that he could install it and run the app on his phone with no issue ?